# How to combine "the last but one" and "the last but three" together?

Tags: grammar

**If A ranks the last but one and B ranks the last but three, so the combination of them should be the follow ? :**

```
A and B rank the last but one and three respectively?
```

Answer (score 1):

"A and B rank the last but one and the last but three respectively" seems to sound better - "the last but X" is a full phrase, and personally I wouldn't break it down like that.

It would be better to reword this sentence, though:

> "A and B rank second and fourth to last respectively".

If you want to get fancy, you can even say:

> "A and B rank penultimate and preantepenultimate respectively"

but that borders on ridiculously obtuse.

Comment: Why the final one is obtuse?

Comment: @PingTang "Preantepenultimate" is, let's say, not the word you'd find pretty much anywhere outside the dictionary. You can [check the n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preantepenultimate%2C+penultimate) - it's used very rarely and it seems to be fairly specific to phonetics and language studies. Still, it is a valid word meaning "fourth to last".

Comment: "second to last" and "fourth to last" are the common ways to express this idea. Once you pass second to last, it's much more common to say how far they are from the front than from the back. If there were, say, ten competitors, people would be much more likely to say "Bob came in sixth" then "Bob came in fourth from last". If you were talking about a contest with hundreds of competitors, "fourth from last" would be less strange. And of course you might be trying to emphasize that he was a loser.

Comment: There's an old joke about two lifelong rivals both entering a contest, and afterward one tells his friends, "I came in second, and Jones was next to last." Without mentioning that the two of them were the only ones in the competition.